# error in mysql_fetch_assoc();

Tags: php, mysql

I keep having an error in `mysql_fetch_(assoc,array,row)` I can't find the problem and when I try to count the rows of the result by using echo the result is 1

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\wamp\www\Jocales\login.php on line 88
>   in query SELECT * FROM users WHERE uName ='nuha' AND uPassword = '123'

```
 <?php 

   $login= $_POST['login']; 
   $password= $_POST['password'];

      if($login && $password){
       $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")or die ('no connection');
       mysql_select_db("jocales",$con) or die ('no');
       $query= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uName ='$login' AND uPassword = '$password'";
       $result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error()." in query $query");

       $record=mysql_fetch_assoc($query) or die(mysql_error()." in query $query"); 
  ?>
```

Comment: Check `mysql_error()` to see what is wrong. Besides, have a look at [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) and [`mysqli`](http://php.net/mysqli) as `mysql_x` functions are deprecated! Furthermore in the posted form your code is wide open to SQL injections.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$record=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)
```

To

```
$record=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
```

**Note:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

**WARNING:** You code is vulnerable to **SQL Injection**.

Answer (score 0):

The function `mysql_fetch_assoc()` expects one parameter and it should be a `resource` type. You're providing a string.

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uName ='$login' AND uPassword = '$password'";
$result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error()." in query $query");

//this is the issue!
$record = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) or die(mysql_error()." in query $query");
```

the last statement should be

```
$record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) or die(mysql_error()." in query $query");
```

---

## NOTE (straight from php.net about mysql_*)

## Warning

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and **will be removed in the future**. Instead, the **MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used**. See also MySQL: [choosing an API guide](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) and [related FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

use this code ( replace `$query` with `$result` )

```
<?php 

   $login= $_POST['login']; 
   $password= $_POST['password'];

      if($login && $password){
       $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")or die ('no connection');
       mysql_select_db("jocales",$con) or die ('no');
       $query= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uName ='$login' AND uPassword = '$password'";
       $result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error()." in query $query");

       $record=mysql_fetch_assoc($result) or die(mysql_error()." in query $query"); 
  ?>
```